A supermassive white hole that emits much more matter
Just as a supermassive black hole consumes a lot of material, does a supermassive white hole also expel a lot of material? If yes then how? I am puzzled by the thought of where the matter would come from near a supermassive white hole?

Did you read the comments on your previous question? White holes (if they even exist, which is highly doubtful) do not expel infinite matter. There is no way for the matter to have gotten in there, and also no mechanism to produce it.

Previous post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/835041/174766

White holes can exist only in an eternal universe that existed forever. In such a universe, a white hole appears before the infinite past of the universe and explodes with matter coming out of nowhere similarly to the Big Bang, just much smaller. In the infinite past of the universe all this matter crosses the anti-horizon of the white hole and starts flying away randomly. This makes the white hole progressively smaller until it disappears completely. No new matter is created or crosses the anti-horizon after the infinite past of the universe. This is the same as a black hole backward in time.


Does a supermassive white hole also expel a lot of material ?

No, or at least not necessarily. It is a mistake to think of a white hole as a black hole "in reverse". A supermassive white hole would distort spacetime and hence attract external matter in just the same way as a black hole of equivalent mass. However, most models of white holes find that they are unstable and, if they exist at all, they will only exist for a very short time. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hole:

In general relativity, a white hole is a hypothetical region of spacetime and singularity that cannot be entered from the outside ... Like black holes, white holes have properties such as mass, charge, and angular momentum. They attract matter like any other mass ... Another widespread idea is that white holes would be very unstable, would last a very short time and even after forming could collapse and become black holes.


“white hole would distort spacetime and hence attract external matter” - This happens to be incorrect due to the incomplete time reversal. For example, if this were true, then the proper time of a falling observer would end at the antihorizon thus making the antihorizon a physical singularity. The complete time reversal is described by the maximally extended solution, in which the white hole is repulsive. You can clearly see on the Penrose diagram that no causal geodesics can point toward the antihorizon, but only away from it: https://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/insidebh/penrose_schwpar.gif
